# System-reference problems in Visual Studio 2015 with VB.NET 3.5

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

We have a **VB.NET project** which targets **.NET Framework 3.5**.

[image: Visual Studio settings]

The project **compiles correctly with Visual Studio 2013**. But **not with Visual Studio 2015**:

> error BC30652: Reference required to assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' containing the type 'XmlDictionaryReader'. Add one to your project.

We can fix the problem by adding reference to the System.Runtime.Serialization but I'm interested to know why we are seeing this problem in VS2015 but not in VS2013.

It seems that there are **3 DLLs** which give these errors:

- System.Runtime.Serialization version 3.0.0.0
- System.Web.Services 2.0.0.0
- System.ServiceModel 3.0.0.0

The project contains many references to other System.* DLLs but we are not seeing any errors in these.

And to be clear, **I can open the same solution with the same computer with VS2013 and compile it without problems.** We're just trying to open the same solution with 2015 and trying to compile it. We're not changing anything (targeted .NET Framework etc).

Any ideas what has changed between 2013 and 2015 to cause this?

Comment: Everything has changed in VS2015, it has a completely new VB.NET compiler.  Written from scratch, based on the Roslyn project.  Indirect assembly references are always iffy, non-zero odds you get this warning when you use something like WCF or DataContract serialization.